# Cloning of objects In Salesforce before inserting

Tags: apex

I am making some objects with some fields populated according to the logic.I want to do create of some copy of the object before inserting. Is there any work around

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the `clone` method offered by Apex? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about clone a record of an object, I would recommend you as @Anamdaeya said, the clone method. You can create an apex trigger and `clone` the object and then do whatever you want with it. An example will be like this:

```
            Order_Line_Item__c secondLine = new Order_Line_Item__c();
            secondLine=line.clone(false,true);
            secondLine.Ln__c=lineNumber;
            secondLine.Id=null;
            insert secondLine;
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Manuelanoo, will it do clone and copy every field

Comment: Glad to help you. Please if this answer your question, mark it as best answer :)

Comment: @MANUELAN00 - please see [Community Etiquette](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed) about soliciting solved answers